# unexpected Logout approximately in 30-60 seconds after login

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I wrote a site using .netCore and locally everything works perfect. But on server I can't stay logged in for a long time. It takes 30-60 sec to kick me out to login page and I need to log in again.

My hosting allows me to use up to 1 gb memory for a process. But I have this logs in  Application_pool_exceeded_limits.log:
17:33:59 A worker process with process id of '253876' serving application pool 'u123456789.plsk.[hostingname].com(domain)(4.0)(pool)' has requested a recycle because it reached its virtual memory limit.

I decided to check if this problems occurs if I delete everything but login page. Anyway this problem occurs.

That is my web.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <configuration>
      <system.web>
       <identity impersonate="true" />
       <machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps"
                   decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" 
                   validation="HMACSHA256" 
                   decryption="Auto" />
        <sessionState regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" 
                      timeout="60" 
                      cookieName="MyCookie" 
                      cookieless="UseCookies" />
      </system.web>
      <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
      <system.webServer>
       <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
       <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
       </modules>
     <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
     </handlers>
     <aspNetCore processPath=".\Account.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is best practice, but I was able to resolve the problem by changing "System.GC.Server" to "false" in `[appName].runtimeconfig.json`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change the Virtual Memory Limit:

1. Open IIS Manager.
2. In the Connections panel, select Application Pools.
3. In the Application Pools panel, select the application pool being used.
4. In the Actions panel, click Advanced Settings...
5. Scroll down to the Recycling section.
6. Change the value of Virtual Memory Limit (KB) to 0.
7. Click OK.

Comment: unfortunately my hosting provider doesn't allow users to change pool settings